# modal window with non square borders

Tags: window, modal-dialog

How do I make modal windows with non square borders, for instance a modal window which has a corner to indicate it's coming (sorta being shout) from a text.

Comment: we need more info than you have provided to give you any sort of reasonably helpful answer to your question. what platform, framework, languages are you working with would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

Create your modal dialog window as you would normally and then call [`SetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102(VS.85).aspx) API to set the non-rectangular region you want to achieve.

Note that this will not allow you to do semi-transparent effects, it works only for opaque windows. If you want alpha blending, your window has to be top-level (alpha transparency is not supported for child windows) and you should be usign different APIs.

Also, this works for C++ clients using the native Win32 API. If you are writing C#/VB.Net code, you need to specify if you are using WinForms or WPF, as the solution is different for these.

Comment: What API would you use for alpha transparency?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know at this point. I haven't done Win programming for almost 4 years now. Sorry about that.

For Win32, you need to configure your window to be layered (`SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);`), create alpha-blended bitmap and update the window with it (using `UpdateLayeredWindow`). But I don't remember the details.